# Differentiate or integrate to find a power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was just introduced to the concept of integrating/differentiating to find a power series, but I'm unsure about which method to use. Does it matter? Is it a matter of convenience?

Comment: It depends upon the specific problem.

Comment: You differentiate when you need to get an $n$ (or relative) on top. You integrate when you want to get an $n$ on the bottom.

Comment: Or, vice versa, to get rid of an $n$ on the bottom or top, respectively :D

Comment: Look, provided that you obey the interval of convergence of the powerseries (kind of the Domain of the powerseries), you can integrate, differentiate, even multiply by number or a variable, then integrate or differentiate again. It helps us to find sums of particular series, but it realy depends on the problem in what order these operations are to be done. It's like a puzzle. Don't forget when you integrate, that a constant is added, which turns out to be zero most of the time, but certainly not always!